# How is the generic java erasure affecting the usage of newInstance()?

Tags: java, generics, erasure

Based on the java documentation:

> During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type
>   parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type
>   parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.

Now, the thing is, with a class like that:

```
public class MyCreator<T> { 
    Class<T> kind; 

    MyCreator(Class<T> kind) {
        this.kind = kind; 
    }

    void printInstanceClass() throws Exception{ 
        System.out.println(kind.newInstance().getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
        MyCreator<String> myCreator = new MyCreator<String>(String.class);

        myCreator.printInstanceClass();
    } 
}
```

the `printInstanceClass()` method is printing actually "class java.lang.String".

If the compiler is replacing T inside of the class with Object, I guess that also the information on Class associated with `kind` is removed and replaced with Class. So, how can the `newInstance()` method return a String instance instead of an Object one?

Comment: You should try and see what happens if you remove the type parameter ```T```, and use ```Class``` as a raw type. It will still print ```class java.lang.String```, meaning this information is not just stored in the type parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part is the `String.class` *parameter*. It's not a *type parameter*, but a plain old param, like `String[] args`. So, the `Class<T> kind` will be `String.class` thus the `printInstanceClass()` can access it at runtime.

It's a common practice, suggested in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) too.

So after type erasure this code is logically equivalent to this one:

```
public class MyCreator { 
    Class kind; // this will be String.class at runtime

    MyCreator(Class kind) {
        this.kind = kind; 
    }

    void printInstanceClass() throws Exception{ 
        System.out.println(kind.newInstance().getClass());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
        MyCreator myCreator = new MyCreator(String.class);

        myCreator.printInstanceClass();
    } 
}
```

Comment: String.class returns an instance of type Class<String>. This is not a subtype of Class<Object>, and thus your code would not compile. Maybe you meant to use Class<?> instead?

Comment: My code is just a rough demonstration of what it would look like after decompiling the compiled code. Anyway, I should've been more precise. Updating the code with something that compiles.

Comment: So, the difference between this snippet and the one I posted is that the one with the type parameters allows to tie the class passed in the constructor to the parameter that makes that class specific. Right?
Without the generic, we can pass whatever class in the constructor, with the  generic we can control what to pass and make the class behaving differently based on the generic parameter itself.

Answer (score 2):

You pass String.class (which is NOT erased, but a concrete class retained at runtime), then call newInstance on that class, which yields a String.

The output examines the concrete object (String) and displays its class.

Comment: You mean that since we are passing the class as an argument of the constructor and not through the generic arguments, that won't be erased by the compiler?

Comment: Exactly - erasure only affects type paremeters, not concrete objects

Answer (score 1):

Information about the class (type) you passed as generic argument of your `myCreator` object is erased, but not information stored inside the `kind` object.

Using `Class<?>` object methods is fine, but if you tried to obtain class information from generic `T` type you'd encounter a compilation error, for instance:

```
void printInstanceClass() throws Exception{ 
    System.out.println(T.class.newInstance().getClass()); // error!
}
```

Although it's not easy, workarounds for doing the above exist too.